# Powershell: Exclude numerous folders with -notmatch statement

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I'm creating a small script which will list EXE files on the computer.

```
$computername = get-content env:computername
get-childitem C: -recurse | ? {$_.fullname -notmatch 'C:\\Windows'} | where {$_.extension -eq ".exe"} | format-table fullname | Out-File "\\server\incomming\$computername.txt"
```

The problem is that -notmatch doesn't accept more statements. I could copy-paste `? {$_.fullname -notmatch 'C:\\Windows'}` and use for other folders like Program Files (x86), Program Files and so on. But I wouldn't like to bloat a script too much.

Is there a way I could exclude numerous folders with -notmatch statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the logical operators like `-and` for more complex logical expressions.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ -Recurse | Where-Object { ($_.FullName -notmatch "C:\\Windows") -and ($_.FullName -notmatch "C:\\Program Files") }
```

For many paths, I'd add them to an array or a hash table before calling `Get-ChildItem` and use `Where-Object` check if the pipeline file object path is present in the array or hash table. Eventually, you have to list the paths somewhere, but not necessarily in a single command. For example:

```
$excludedPaths = @("C:\Windows", "C:\Program Files");
Get-ChildItem C:\ -Recurse | Where-Object { $excludedPaths -notcontains $_.Directory }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers!

And is it possible to get output longer than it is now?

It is now something like 100 symbols and then it ends with dots if path is longer than that.
I've get something like this -
C:\my files\my programs\prog...

Comment: PowerShell does this to make the output readable in table formatting. You can always save the results to a file (e.g. `| Export-Csv`), or use `| Format-List` which will break lines instead of adding ellipses. `| Select-Object -Property FullName | Format-List` will return just the file names.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
get-childitem -literalpath e:\*.exe -Recurse | where { $_.DirectoryName -notmatch "Windows" -and $_.DirectoryName -notmatch "MyOtherFiles"}
```

Comment: `$_.DirectoryName` is no good, you would still get matches for files in eg. `\Windows\System32`

Comment: DirectoryName is just the item folder in String format, if you want to be precise you want to replace the -notmatch with -ne and spell out the folder name, i.e. $_.DirectoryName -ne "e:\windows"